# Как реализовать работу высоконагруженного Qt-[видео]виджета?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, видео, qthread

Задумался о том, как можно было бы реализовать Qt-плеер. Декодирование кадров происходит вне Qt. Со стороны Qt требуется только выводить кадры через `paintEvent()` + `QImage`. Нашёл механизм, позволяющий смувать любой объект Qt в созданный `QThread` - `QObject::moveToThread()`, но есть ограничение:

> The object cannot be moved if it has a parent.

Виджет в любом случае будет иметь родителя, иначе он бесполезен. Представим себе, что нужно выводить 4K кадры при 60 FPS. Я сомневаюсь, что основной поток Qt нормально с этим справится.

**Подскажите, есть ли решение этой проблемы? Или, может быть, я не прав и всё должно быть ОК?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что у Вас немного смещалось в голове разное.

Вначале о объекта в поток. Это нужно для одной основной цели - кто будет обслуживать очередь сообщений этого объекта. По умолчанию, берется поток родителя этого объекта. Именно поэтому там и написано, что нельзя перемещать объекты, которые имеют родителя. Но никто не мешает просто создать объект и поместить его в подходящий поток.

Виджеты должны работать в основном потоке, так устроен UI в большинстве фреймворков. Иначе очень сложно обрабатывать все. Qt не исключение - рисовать не из главного потока на виджетах нельзя. Вариант ответа на этот вопрос на [en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258346/drawing-from-multiple-threads-in-qt), на [форуме Qt](https://forum.qt.io/topic/43362/how-to-paint-on-a-different-thread/8).

Теперь к 4k@60. Наверное, Вы хотите воспроизоводить видео. В этом случае нужно будет ещё и заниматься декодированием его. Вот именно этим могут заниматься дополнительные потоки, подготавливая картинки в памяти. А основной поток уже будет их подставлять.

4k это 3840 x 2160. Если один пиксель 4 байта, то это 31 мегабайт данных на кадр или  1.8 гигабайта. это много. Поэтому, большинство плееров давно не рисуют напрямую. Обычно используются возможности видеокарты, а приложение просто предоставляет место для отрисовки (поэтому, иногда, когда делается скриншот окна с плеером, там бывает черный экран).

Comment: Я пишу обертку над FFmpeg, декодирование будет происходить там. Затем хочу написать обёртку для Qt. Вот и думаю, как это сделать. Уж не знаю, что использует FFmpeg для декодирования. Возможно его можно переключить на видеокарту или он это сам делает... Нужно будет разобраться с этим.

Comment: Меня интересует только вывод картинок со стороны Qt. Ну еще субтитры рисовать через `drawText`, для аудио как раз можно будет создать отдельный топ левел виджет и двинуть в другой поток.

Comment: рисовать субтитры умеет и ffmpeg. Может так даже легче будет.

Comment: вот пример как раз для Вас https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV